# Why is this map lambda function taking too much time when applied on pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to copy each row from `df_source` to `df_target` that matches a simple condition (value of its `col1` doesn't exist in a given list of values).

I'm trying to accomplish this by doing the following:

```
df_target = df_source[df_source['Col1'].map(lambda x: x not in id_list)].copy()
```

Keep in mind `len(id_list) = 300000`, that contains string identifiers of the shape `HF1D2R`.
The dataframe `df_source` also contains 300000 rows and 11 columns of type strings and integers.

This takes over 10 minutes to complete, what's the issue here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) with `~` for inverse boolean mask:

```
df_target = df_source[~df_source['Col1'].isin(id_list)].copy()
```